# adding an Icon next to title doesn't work on Mac

Tags: python, pyqt5, titlebar

I would like to add A LOGO next to Icon but it doesn't seem to work on Mac , any suggestions for [this]

[image: 1]

code :

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon-cutout.png'))
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__), 'icon-cutout.png')
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(path))
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

it only appears in [here]

[image: 2]

Comment: It seems that you used a full path for the application icon, and not for the window. Remember that relative paths are always based on the cwd, try to set the window icon path just like you did for the other.

Comment: Hi , both icons are set with the same way , i tried to change it but its doesn't affect the window.

Comment: Wait, now that I think of it, macOS does *not* show the window icon in the title bar, it eventually shows the icon for the *current document*. See the note about [`windowIcon()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop).

Comment: Yes that's what i came up with eventually , thanks .